# Implicit Functions With 2 Variables

Tags: matlab

Thanks to the `fimplicit` function, I can plot implicit functions with 2 variables `(x,y)`.

For a particular `x`, there is a particular `y` which makes `F_imp=0`. Now take this `y` as an input to another function `g` which produces `z`.

How can I plot `x,z` for x's between [0.1 1]?

Of course, I could have found the inverse of g(y) and replace in F(x,y) but there is not closed form of inverse of g(y).

Below are the functions I am dealing with:

```
F_imp = @(x,y) log(100-x*90) - x*log(10+0.9*y) - (1-x)*log(100-0.1*y);
fimplicit(F_imp,[0.1 1 0 100])

g=0.1*log(10+y*0.9)+0.9*log(100-0.1*y)
```

Comment: it's a little bit confusing. You mean (x,y) are inputs of F_imp. Then you say F_imp produces y. Please check the used letters, otherwise we can't understand the problem.

Comment: I edited the question. To wrap up, 1st, for some x, find y which makes the F_imp equal to 0 and 2nd use this y to find z(with function g). You can think of it as a composite function. And I want to see the relation between first input x and final output z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ImplicitFunctionLine` object, which is an optional return value of the `fimplicit()` function. In this way you get access to the correspondent `x` and `y` data.
Then just use `y` to calculate `g` and plot `g` against `x`:

```
clear;

F_imp = @(x,y) log(100-x*90) - x*log(10+0.9*y) - (1-x)*log(100-0.1*y);
fp = fimplicit(F_imp,[0.1 1 0 100]); %returns the ImplicitFunctionLine object

%get calculated data points from the object
x = fp.XData;
y = fp.YData;

%set y as input for g
g=0.1*log(10+y*0.9)+0.9*log(100-0.1*y);

plot(x, g);
grid minor;
```

Here is the result:

[image: calculating a third variable through the fimplicit return object]